# Include JS file after Ext in Sencha CMD

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2 application (non MVC), it works well, except for one JS file. In there I define a store.
In `app.json` I included `sencha-touch.js` and this file also. It is building properly, but when I open the page it is saying that

```
Object has no method 'create'
```

My app.json:

```
{
    "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
    "x-bootstrap": true
},
{
    "path": "res/mystore.js"
},
{
    "path": "bootstrap.js",
    "x-bootstrap": true
},
{
    "path": "app.js",
    "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
    "update": "delta"
}
```

I tried many things, but nothing seems to be working, change the sequence, x-bootstrap to true for mystore.js, but nothing. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was the order. After I changed like this:

```
{
    "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
    "x-bootstrap": true
},
{
    "path": "bootstrap.js",
    "x-bootstrap": true
},
{
    "path": "app.js",
    "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
    "update": "delta"
},
{
    "path": "res/mystore.js"
}
```

it works perfectly.